# Adding values to text+number string

Tags: excel

I hope somebody can help me. I am completely out of ideas. I have a very large data set that has unique codes assigned to each name with some code repetition which should be eliminated.

```
Codes
ER0001
ER0002
ER0003
etc
```

I need to make sure that all codes have values between 1 to 1000 and that the code is not repeated. 
Thus that I have between ER0001 to ER1000. 
e.g. 
Code 
ER0001
ER0001 needs to be changed to ER0002?

Thank you.

Comment: Considering your happy to change a duplicate code without needing to change anything else, why not just loop through all the values and change them all to guarantee no duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I would be happy to auto change values if there are duplicates. How can you loop it, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If *Codes* is in A1, put *ER0001* in A2 and *ER0002* in A3. Select A2:A3.

[image: Fill Handle Series]

Double click the small black square *Fill Handle* in the lower right of the selection border.

[image: Fill Handle Series]

Your code *series* should fill down to the extents of neighboring data.

Comment: However I do not mean auto fill the codes down. I have codes assigned to specific data in the cell next to it. Some codes are EC0001 and others ER0001. I need to make sure that the numbers in this code such as 0001, 0002 etc are not repeated. I reckon I just need to know how to change a number in the code without going through all of the cells one by one.